# Pass argument to event hook

Tags: php, hooks, events

How do I pass arguments to my hook function?

```
my_function($arg1, $arg2){
    echo $arg1 . " " . $arg2;
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_function');
```

If I want my_function to echo "hello world" for instance, how would I send those parameters with the action hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest first read the wordpress documentation about [actions](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/) to understand how they work.

Actions are aplit into two section, `add_action` and `do_action`

`do_action` is the "location" where you hook into it.

A basic example of `do_action`

```
do_action('my_custom_action');
```

You can also pass arguments into `do_action` which can be available in `add_action` if you choose to use them.

Example for `do_action` with arguments

```
do_action('my_custom_action', 'Hello', 'World!');
```

From the second argument forward every argument can be available in `add_action`

Now that we have a action we can hook into we can do the following

Basic hook (callback function) without parameters (we use the `my_custom_action` action)

```
add_action('my_custom_action', 'my_callback_func');
function my_callback_func () {
    // your login here
}
```

Hook with parameters. We know that `my_custom_action` has two arguments we can use, in order to make them available we can do the following

```
add_action('my_custom_action', 'my_callback_func', 10, 2);
function my_callback_func ($param1, $param2) {
    echo $param1 . ' ' . $param2;
}
```

The output of out callback function will be `Hello World!`.

I will not go into detail what every part of `add_action('my_custom_action', 'my_callback_func', 10, 2)` means, wordpress has a great documentaion about this.

Some `add_actions` will have arguments, some will not, you will need to explore each `do_action` you want to hook into to see what is available to you to use.

A great plugin that I use constantly when developing in wordpress is [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/), amazing plugin for when you want to understand what action are being used on the current page, what priorety each callback function has, what arguments it uses and so on.

Again, first read the wordpress documentation about hooks, actions and filters, it will give you a much better understating on how they work and how to work with them.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation of add_action() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/), you have to pass the number of parameters for your action with the `accepted_args` parameter.

This code should be great:

```php
my_function($arg1, $arg2){
    echo $arg1 . " " . $arg2;
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_function', 10, 2 );
```

And just call the action like this:

```php
do_action( 'init', 'hello', 'world' );
```

Comment: `init` is a core hook, and manually running it could cause a lot of problems.